# how to implement android search in windows application desktop vb.net c# sharp

Tags: android-search

Here I want to Implement a search like android , like return those Rows of column which any of its word begin with what user search .(Here SQL SERVER , VB.net , Ado.net I am using )

I have a column named suppose ArticleName values Like

- Mahesh Nagar
- Manish  Nagar
- Shan mani
- List item

Ghanshaym rama

Now when i start search **'MA**' result would be 
**Ma**hesh Nagar
**Ma**nish  Nagar 
Shan **ma**ni

Ghanshaym rama should not select as it contains ma but second word not start with ma.

AND when Type **"SH"**
Result would be 
**Sh**an mani
same other rows are exclude because in column value not any of word start with sh

Answer (score 0):

this solution is fit for my problem

using System;

using System.Collections.Generic;

using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication2

{

```
class Program

{

    static void Main(string[] args)

    {

        List<string> lstNames = 

       new List<string>() { "Mahesh Nagar", "Manish Nagar", 

                            "Shan Mani", "Ghanshaym rama" };           

        string toSearch = "Sh";

        string[] stringSeparators = new string[] { " " };

        lstNames

        .ForEach( str=>

           {

                if (str

                        .Split(stringSeparators, StringSplitOptions.None)

                          .Any(i => i.StartsWith(toSearch))

                    )                    

            Console.WriteLine(str.Replace(toSearch, "<b>" + toSearch + "</b>"));                    

          });            

        Console.ReadKey();

    }

}
```

}

For more details refer this url 
http://www.dotnetfunda.com/forums/show/20669/how-to-implement-android-search-in-windows-application-desktop-vbnet-c